# JS, HTML, Firebase error with OAuth with redirect authentication

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am getting an error when trying to make a simple website with HTML, JS, and Firebase. The error is as follows:

> [  0.330s] [firebase-auth] Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth >operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, >linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (THIS IS THE >URL... BUT ITS NOT. MWAH HA HA...) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the >Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

I have authorized it in firebase multiple times, but I still get the error. Help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check in the browser console. there should be a network request getProjectConfig. Can you provide the response of that?

Comment: I didn't see a getProjectConfig. I will research that...